# Javascript onchange event not working

Tags: javascript, html

I did this code up trying to hide a select input field until the check box is checked. It works but when the page first loads these are all visible. I need them invisible until the check box is filled in. If I load the page then click the checkbox and then uncheck the check box the object disappears so I know it's working but why does it appear at the beginning and more importantly how do I stop it from doing that?

Code:

```js
function doruc() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("secondhalf1"),
      checkBox = document.getElementById("pizza11");
  elem.style.display = checkBox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="pizza22" onclick="doruc()" name="halfHalf2" />
```

Comment: Why is the checkbox id is pizza22 while the checkbox in javascript function id is pizza11, are there multiple checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `doruc` function in global scope after document ready state and then calling that function will set the style to `none`.

```
<script>
    function doruc() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("secondhalf1"),
        checkBox = document.getElementById("pizza11");
        elem.style.display = checkBox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
     };

   doruc();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can solve your problem.

```
  if(pizza22) {
    secondhalf1.style.display="none";
  }
  pizza22.onchange = function() {
        if(secondhalf1.style.display==="none") {secondhalf1.style.display="";}
      else if(secondhalf1.style.display==="") {secondhalf1.style.display="none";secondhalf1};
  }
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x22ugdmm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your name of ID in JavaScript is not matching to your element. In JavaScript there is pizza11 and in input tag there is pizza22. So look into that.
2 nd reason is you didn't call your function, you just defined it.

```js
function doruc() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("secondhalf1"),
      checkBox = document.getElementById("pizza11");
  elem.style.display = checkBox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
doruc();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="pizza11" onclick="doruc()" name="halfHalf2" />
```

Try this it will work.